# How to access SVN repository in XCode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, svn, repository, xcode4.2

Now, i switched to developing from Xcode 4.2. In Xcode 3.2.5 i have used SVN repository to save my project details. But, in XCode 4.2 i dont know how to access SVN Repository? Can you please tell me what are the steps i need to follow to access SVN from XCode 4.2? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Windows > Organizer > Repositories > Add Repositories (bottom left +) > Type - Subversion

Answer (score 1):

In XCode 4.4, I had some problems viewing repos that were setup in XCode 4.2.  One of the great features of XCode is it's ability to connect to repo and show whether a file has been modified by showing an "M" next to the class file that hasn't been committed yet.  When I added a new repo as I had before (the GameBit method), all of my projects stopped showing the "M" or "A" and all the commit messages weren't visible in the Organizer, and my trunk/branches/tags folder were disconnected (red dot).

When this happens, the first thing you should do is close the project and quit XCode.  That should reset the svn configs of all your projects.

If that doesn't work, open Terminal and enter this command to checkout your new working copy:

> svn co (http or https)://YOURsvnSERVERurl/PROJECTNAME(name of your new project folder you just added to Organizer)

That immediately resulted in all previous projects in the Organizer > Repositories to show the commit messages again and linked everything up as it was before.  However, the new project still didn't show the "M" and "A" until I quit XCode and rebooted.

This answer is meant for anyone who tries to add a project under svn to XCode's source control management system and XCode is not showing the commit status.